# C# and SerialPort Class truncating data

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have a C# application that uses the .NET SerialPort class. The code that I use to pick up data from the serial port is nothing special. The key parts are

```
//Open the port
            comport.BaudRate = myPort.BaudRate;
            comport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            comport.DataBits = 8;
            comport.Parity = Parity.None;
            comport.ReadTimeout = 20000;


            comport.PortName = myPort.PortSystemName;
            comport.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            comport.RtsEnable = true;


            comport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
comport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            string msg = "";
            try
            {
                msg = comport.ReadExisting();

                if (comport.IsOpen)
                    comport.Close();
         }
```

This code works **perfectly fine in Windows XP**. However, on Windows 7 it runs into issues where no matter what data is sent, it ONLY picks up the first four characters. So in a string like "123456", the msg will be "1234". The device that is collecting the data is an RFIdeas pcProx and I have verified that the data is just fine. I have also verified that the data looks OK in hyperterminal. So there has to be something odd about the way that I'm picking up the data in code. Help!

Comment: Side note: I have found even though the code is the same, a `SerialPort` somehow behaves differently when hosted in a form/control vs manual creation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is entirely consistent with the API. It is not, and never has been, guaranteed to read everything:

> This method returns the contents of the stream and internal buffer of the SerialPort object as a string. This method does not use a time-out. Note that this method can leave trailing lead bytes in the internal buffer, which makes the BytesToRead value greater than zero.

Additionally, you need to handle the "not yet in the internal buffer" - you don't just read while BytesToRead is positive. This usually involves looping and buffering until an entire message is received.

It is your job to read the right amount of data, either by using markers such as line-ends, or by using a length-prefix header.

If it works perfectly fine on XP, then that is good fortune only (and maybe by some timing and/or efficiency tweaks).

Everything above applies equally to most inputs, not just serial ports; for example, file IO and network IO works along pretty much exactly the same principles.

Comment: So you would suggest something like a loop that checks bytestoread as zero? Or what exactly would you suggest from a code perspective?

Comment: @Jim I would expressly **not** look too much at BytesToRead, as that just tells you what is available - it doesn't say there isn't more data coming. If possible, I would use ReadLine(), and use new-lines to separate the data. If you can't use ReadLine(), then yes: you'll need to loop. However: knowing when you have all the data is defined by your protocol. Without some definition (for example, length-prefixed or newline-terminated) it is impossible to tell the difference between "1234" vs "12345 but the 5 is still incoming and has not yet arrived, so only 1234 is available"

Comment: OK, fair enough. I think I can set my device to send a fixed length string longer than any possible data so I could key off the length of the string.